# googleAnalyticsR: Advanced segment returns quite smaller result than GA interface

Tags: r, google-analytics-api

I'm trying to get data out of GA with an advanced segment, combining event action condition AND event label. I'm trying the following:

```
se <- segment_element("ga:eventAction", 
                      operator = "PARTIAL", 
                      type = "DIMENSION", 
                      expressions = "Campaign 1234")

se2 <- segment_element("ga:eventLabel", 
                      operator = "EXACT", 
                      type = "DIMENSION", 
                      expressions = "Start")

sv_simple <- segment_vector_simple(list(list(se)))

sv_simple2 <- segment_vector_simple(list(list(se2)))

seg_defined_one <- segment_define(list(sv_simple, sv_simple2))

segment4 <- segment_ga4("test", session_segment = seg_defined_one)

result <- google_analytics_4(my_id, 
                                 date_range = c(start_date, end_date ),
                                 metrics =  c("ga:sessions"),
                                 dimensions = c("ga:date"),
                                 segments = segment4,
                                 anti_sample = TRUE,
                                 max = -1))
```

But this returns quite low number of sessions, compared to the GA interface when the same segment is applied. When I try to run separately the event action and the event label conditions they return the correct data. What's wrong with the combination of the segment elements?

Answer (score 0):

You can also pass in the segment you created in the web UI which you can find the id of via `ga_segment_list()` to help you compare.

But I think the reason is that you are using `anti_sample` - try it without and over the same date period to see if that is closer to the Web UI numbers.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. I'm not using an existing segment because I want to run over 100 segments with different values that change on a monthly basis, so I don't have them saved in GA. At the same time, there's a big number of daily hits and if I don't use anti-sample it won't work at all.

Comment: I'm not sure you need to use segments at all, filters will avoid sampling and looks like what you are trying to do.  segments are better for sequences of actions, you need a more simple "rows that are this and this" rather than "rows that did this, then this"